# SwiftUI equivalent of popoverTouchBar and pressAndHoldTouchBar

Tags: swiftui, nstouchbar, macbookpro-touch-bar

SwiftUI Touch Bar support seems quite limited.

Is there an equivalent of `popoverTouchBar` and `pressAndHoldTouchBar`?

I tried doing a popover as follows:

```
.touchBar {
     Button(action: { self.showRadiusTouchBarSlider.toggle() }) {
        Text("Radius")
     }.popover(isPresented: self.$showRadiusTouchBarSlider) {
        Slider(value: self.$model.radius, in: Float(0.0)...Float(1.0))
     }
}
```

Amusingly, that puts a touch-bar styled slider in the corner of the screen:

[image: Touch Bar slider]

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for that?

Comment: @Heisenbug nope. I just changed the design to avoid the popovers.